# Everytime i refresh my react app, it shows me 404 file not found

Tags: reactjs, github-actions, github-pages

I'm trying to deploy my small react app, but every time I logged in and refresh the page, the 404 file not found appears. I'm using local storage to save the data of the current user. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong and how to fixed these.

These is my repository https://github.com/GabrielDelaPena/expenses_tracker.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The simple way to fix this:

1. Create a file named **"_redirects"** in your public folder
2. Just add this code to the file `/*    /index.html  200`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using React router, then you can solve this issue by using HashRouter instead of BrowserRouter.

For more knowledge on  this, you can refer to this thread:
[React-router urls don't work when refreshing or writing manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually)

Comment: There are an infinite number of reasons why an app would have a 404 error. Incorrectly setting router urls could be one, but there's no indication in the question that that's the case, and searching their repo for "BrowserRouter" shows nothing. Take a look again at [answer] to see how to post a specific answer that is relevant to a specific question

Comment: For what it's worth, this answer solved my issue.